# Linear Transformation defined by trace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Which one of the following is true for the transformation $T : M_n →\mathbb{C}$  defined by $T(A) = trA =\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{ii} $?
(a) Nullity of $T$ is $n^2$$ - 1$
(b) Rank of $T$ is $n$
(c) $T$ is one-to-one
(d) $T(AB) =T(A) T(B) $
Answer : (c) If we take $n=2$ then
$T($\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\   \end{pmatrix}$) =0$ and
$T ($\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$)  =0$
Hence $T$ is not one - one.
(d)$ T(I. I) =T(I)=n \neq T(I) T(I) =n^2$
Hence option d is false also.
(a) the matrix of $T$ will be $2×n^2$ which will look like

1  0  0 after n zeroes 1  0  0...
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0...
So Rank $T$=$1$ and Nullity =$n^2 - 1$
So option (a) true and option (b) false.
I'm unable to write the 2 by $n^2$ matrix in latex. So, anybody kindly edit this please.
Is my description right. If not please show me the correct way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm reading your argument correctly then you're right, (a) is the correct answer. The rank of $T$ is clearly $1$, hence the nullity of $T$ is $n^2 - 1$. Your counterexamples for (c) and (d) are fine. This is assuming that the base field is $\mathbb C$ for both the domain and codomain.

Comment: No. I think the base field should be $\mathbb{R} $ for the domain. Is not it?

Comment: If that is true then the image is only $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb C$, in which case it's a bit strange to call the codomain $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Since the dimension of $\mathbb{C} $ over $\mathbb{R} $ is 2 that is why the matrix of Linear transformation is 2 by $n^2$ otherwise if it would be 1 by $n^2$.

Comment: If tha base field of domain is $\mathbb{C} $ then if the trace of a matrix becomes $i$ then rank of$T$ will become 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are ultimately correct. However, the base field of the domain, unless the producer of this question has made something intentionally bizarre, should be $\Bbb C$.

Your argument for a,b can be much more efficient. In particular: because $T$ is a map to $\Bbb C$, the rank of $T$ must be either $0$ or $1$. Because $T$ is not the zero map (for instance, because $T(I) \neq 0$), it must have rank $1$. By the rank-nullity theorem, it follows that the nullity is $n^2 - 1$.

Comment: Can you please explain why the rank of $T $ can only be 0 or 1?

Comment: The rank of $T$ is the dimension of the image. The image is a subspace of the one-dimensional codomain $\Bbb C$, so its dimension must be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: You have mentioned that if the base field is not $\mathbb{C} $ something bizarre will happen. Can you please tell me how it will create the bizarre? Please Share your idea.

Comment: @Math-Learner It is not that "something bizarre might happen". It is that it would, in and of itself, be bizarre to ask a question in which the codomain is $\Bbb C$, but the base field is not $\Bbb C$ in the context of an introductory linear algebra course.